# Why does software often use an inverse coordinate system compared to regular math coord system?

Tags: math, coordinate-systems, coords

As you likely know, in c#, the origin (0,0) of a plane is the upperleft corner. Going to the right and/or under is regarded as +, while going to the left and/or up is -. Opposed to this  is the regular math coordsystem:

(0,0)=mid of plane, going up/right = +, down/left = -.

It's kinda counter-intuitive and can be annoying sometimes, since we're used (for years) to using the regular math coords, and you have to recalculate coords as well.

Is this a fundamental design flaw? And do you get used to it after a while? And which other languages use a different coord system like c#?

Comment: all computer graphics coordinate system have the upper left corner as (0, 0), unless there is some strange systems I don't know

Comment: In OpenGL the origin is in the bottom left

Comment: @samgak: Are you sure it's not in the middle?

Comment: @samgak It is (and the axis are) what I tell it to be :} Hooray for space transformations.

Comment: @user2864740: You can define a mapping from a custom coordinate system onto the OpenGL coordinates (using a view matrix), but the OpenGL coordinates don't change.

Comment: @BenVoigt in the case of glReadPixels 0,0 is the bottom left. For NDC you're right it's the middle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not C# but the display that uses a inverse coordinate system, this comes from the days back when the display was drawn in using a CRT and the image was drawn in top to bottom, left to right. That is why the coordinate system OS's use match that.

Languages like C# are just wrapping the underlying OS's API and that is why C# uses it too.

Comment: Had the same answer almost word for word but you beat me to it :)

Comment: CRTs could have swept bottom to top just as easily -- the origin of the top to bottom numbering system is line numbers on a page of text.

Comment: @BenVoigt Maybe, maybe not. I was under the impression it was because VGA defined its data stream as top down.

Comment: I think it goes back even earlier than CRTs, to line printers, essentially automated typewriters. They printed in page-reading order, from left to right then from top to bottom. CRTs inherited their coordinate system, and from there so did many applications.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle: Exactly.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: VGA was a late comer to the world of computer displays.

Comment: Early display output (CGA, VGA, whatever) were effectively just 'bitmaps' onto some prespecified memory region. When viewing these regions (and after being exposed as such) as simple 2D arrays a top-left origin and ascending x/y make sense wrt pixel/cell indexing.

Comment: @user2864740 Thats what I was trying to convey with my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical graph plane is a **virtual** thing, which expands in all directions without limits.

The screen is a **real** thing, which can not really expand at all.

Instead we use the concept of **scrolling** and we are **used to** doing it from a starting point down.

So conceptually the graphics systems all use the same system as a (left-to-right & top-to-bottom) textblock or page in a  book . It is about how we scroll to expand/advance the display area.

But it **could** be defined in any other way; after all e.g. negative coordinates do make sense as opposed to a negative line number..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the coordinate system on the screen, you can create wrapper methods to re-map the coordinates any way you like.